# Google named OpenID shortcut?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, login, google

Is there a way to use a Google named OpenID (profiles.google.com/yourname) without typing it in manually?  I keep clicking on the big "Google" button and getting the hashed openID, which is no longer associated with my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page now has Google Profiles (should it be called Google Accounts?) in the secondary row of icons at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it would be nice if the Login Google Button used `profiles.google.com/yourname` URL instead of the `www.google.com/accounts/` URL

I currently have my login setup to use both. The profile URL is my primary and the account URL is the alt. Once the Google Login Button is re-programmed to use the profiles URL it will still work... but until that happens you have to manually type in the profiles OpenID URL if you want to use that instead.

Comment: this presents something of an upgrade/usability problem for the team: if they change the url that shows up when you click the google button, existing users who use the button will not be able to log in and they won't understand why. but if they have two google buttons, users will probably be confused as to which one to use.